# Merge mutiple CSV file into one workbook (each worksheet will be named with prefix of its original file name) VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to merge mutiple CSV file into one workbook with the code below

```
Sub CombineCsvFiles()

Dim xFilesToOpen As Variant
Dim I As Integer
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xTempWb As Workbook
Dim xDelimiter As String
Dim xScreen As Boolean
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
xScreen = Application.ScreenUpdating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
xDelimiter = "|"
xFilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv), *.csv", , "Kutools for Excel", , True)
If TypeName(xFilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
    MsgBox "No files were selected", , "Kutools for Excel"
    GoTo ExitHandler
End If
I = 1
Set xTempWb = Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(I))
xTempWb.Sheets(1).Copy
Set xWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
xTempWb.Close False
Do While I < UBound(xFilesToOpen)
    I = I + 1
    Set xTempWb = Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(I))
    xTempWb.Sheets(1).Move , xWb.Sheets(xWb.Sheets.Count)
Loop
ExitHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = xScreen
Set xWb = Nothing
Set xTempWb = Nothing
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description, , "Kutools for Excel"
Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

the problem I had was that I was getting my worksheet on the same cell with semicolon as a seperator . For exemple the worksheet "speed" below:

[image: Problem with the worksheet]

Anyone has a solution?

Comment: The problem is that you don't import csv files. What's about your variable `xDelimiter`? Your macro don't use it and it should be a semicolon (;) not a pipe (|).  You open csv files with Excel and copy the sheet to an Excel file. Csv is not an Excel format, it's a simple text file for data exchange. You shouldn't ever open it with Excel, but you can import it with Excel. That's another approach. Try this manually for better understanding: https://www.copytrans.net/support/how-to-open-a-csv-file-in-excel/

Answer (score 0):

How about this? I didn't test it, but it looks pretty darn close.

```
Sub CombineCsvFiles()

    Dim xFilesToOpen As Variant
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xTempWb As Workbook
    Dim xDelimiter As String
    Dim xScreen As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    xScreen = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xDelimiter = "|"
    xFilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv), *.csv", , "Kutools for Excel", , True)
    If TypeName(xFilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "No files were selected", , "Kutools for Excel"
        GoTo ExitHandler
    End If
    I = 1
    Set xTempWb = Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(I))
    xTempWb.Sheets(1).Copy
    Set xWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    xTempWb.Close False
    Do While I < UBound(xFilesToOpen)
        I = I + 1
        Set xTempWb = Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(I))
        xTempWb.Sheets(1).Move , xWb.Sheets(xWb.Sheets.Count)
    Loop
ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = xScreen
    Set xWb = Nothing
    Set xTempWb = Nothing
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, , "Kutools for Excel"
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```